# In what way could I use my code to close a window in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code. All it does is open a window and have a blue button with the word "ice" on it. Once you click the "ice" button, it opens a second window and is supposed to close the second window. But I cant seem to get that to work.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import os.path        

def main():
    #opening first window
    top=Tk()
    #changing window size, color, and name
    top.configure(bg="#AED6F1")
    top.geometry("800x600+300+80")
    top.title()
    #Button to get login screen
    Button_1 =   Button(top,text="Ice",
                        bg="#AED6F1",relief=FLAT,
                        bd=0,font="Times 
                        100 bold",command=secondary)

    Button_1.place(x=0,y=0)
    top.mainloop()
def secondary():
    top.destroy()
main()
```

It just gives the error:

> return self.func(*args) File "E:\Programing\test\Eise.py", line 21, in
>   secondary top.destroy() NameError: name 'top' is not defined

What do I need to add to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`top` is declared as local variable and you need declare this as global variable:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import os.path        

def main():

    #create all windows

    global top, down, left, right # Declare all windows as global

    top = down = left = right = Tk() # All window variables are Tk()

    #changing window size, color, and name
    top.configure(bg="#AED6F1")
    top.geometry("800x600+300+80")
    top.title()
    #Button to get login screen
    Button_1 = Button(top, text="Ice",
                        bg="#AED6F1",relief=FLAT,
                        bd=0,font="Times 100 bold",command=secondary)

    Button_1.place(x=0,y=0)
    top.mainloop()
def secondary():
#destroy all windows
    top.destroy()
    down.destroy()
    left.destroy()
    right.destroy()
main()
```

Comment: @Firebully11 Yes, look my answer again

Comment: @Firebully11 Please, if my answer is usefull, dont forget mark it as accepted (click on the gray check)

Comment: If i have multiple windows, how do I do it for multiple windows

Comment: @Firebully11 
I'm back, why have you unchecked my answer? What am I missing?

Comment: sorry, i must have miss clicked. you answered everything correctly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You assign `top` inside the function `main` which means it doesn't exist outside that function and therefore the function `secondary` can not find it.

You can change the scope of `top` with `global`:

```
def main():
    global top
    ...
```

Also; you sholuld take a look at [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)